# How to minify JS with AWS CodePipeline

Tags: javascript, minify, aws-codepipeline

I'm currently delivering the code I commit on Github to my static website hosted on AWS S3 using AWS CodePipeline, but I'm manually minifying the JS files before pushing them. Is it possible to add a new step on CodePipeline that will do it for me automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a Build stage and use CodeBuild service to install and invoke the minification command.

Your buildspec.yml file for CodeBuild project may look like:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
      - npm install uglify-js -g
  post_build:
    commands:
      - uglifyjs --compress --mangle -- input.js
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```